# Logout button not working after moving from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

This was my logout button in my main activity and it worked perfectly. By the way, I'm using Firebase and this was a logout button for Google sign-in. It worked as intended when it was in my main class.

```
package com.example.akhilsukh01.truckory;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }
            }
        };

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAuth.signOut();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I know that it won't work with the same code because it's not an activity and it's a different fragment altogether, but I'm not sure how to fix it. This was my attempt (that doesn't work):

```
package com.example.akhilsukh01.truckory;

/**
 * Created by akhil on 7/24/2017.
 */

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class Tab5Profile extends Fragment {

    Button button;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab5profile, container, false);
        return rootView;
        Button logout = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.logout);
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Logout current user
                mAuth.signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine in activity dont change the code. In fragment use

```
((HomeActivity)getActivity).mAuth.signOut();
```

Comment: thank you, where exactly would i put that though, this is what i did. https://jpst.it/123Fe

Comment: Put it on logout.setOnclickListener() in fragment

Comment: i was able to fix every error except "cannot resolve symbol mAuth" now, do you have any idea what the problem may be.

Comment: As i understood you already defined FirebaseAuth mAuth in HomeActivity and initialized it.So dont create a new FirebaseAuth in your fragment. Use HomeActivity's mAuth variable in fragment with code that i wrote in answer

Comment: like this? [        logout.setOnClickListener((HomeActivity)getActivity().mAuth.signOut());
], also i removed the initialization.